# Implement cache in Python

Tags: python, django, caching

I want to implement a basic cache in Python.

It's like this. I've 2 files named :- `cache.py` , `main.py`.

In my cache.py, I want to build a list every 24 hours. So, i run a cronjob `cache.py` every 24 hours which returns me the latest list.

**cache.py**

```
def get_hubcode_threshold_time():
    global threshold_time
    hub_alarm_obj = HubAlarm.objects.all().values('time').distinct()
    for obj in hub_alarm_obj:
        threshold_time.append(obj.time)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_hubcode_threshold_time()
    print threshold_time
```

I run `main.py` every minute (another cronjob). I want to print threshold_time from the cache.

**main.py**

```
import cache
print threshold_time
```

throws an error saying

```
NameError: global name 'threshold_time' is not defined
```

How do I implement a basic cache in Python:?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want multiple processes to be able to access the same data (e.g., the value of `threshold_time`), then you need some sort of persistent storage or a protocol for getting and setting the data. To be more specific, in your `cache.py` file, you need to save the value of `threshold_time` somewhere once you've computed it. Then your `main.py` can retrieve that value from wherever it's been saved.

Just from what you listed, this seems like a particularly good use case for redis, but sqlite or even a text file would also work. Each persistence strategy comes with its own levels of data integrity and complexity.